# JS Remove duplicate div based on attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to remove duplicate entries with same title and src but i don't know how.

```
<ul>
    <li><img class="test" src="secret/photo.jpg" title="Tester1"></li>
    <li><img class="test" src="secret/photo.jpg" title="Tester2"></li>
    <li><img class="test" src="secret/photo.jpg" title="Tester2"></li>
    <li><img class="test" src="secret/photo2.jpg" title="Tester2"></li>
    <li><img class="test" src="secret/photo2.jpg" title="Tester2"></li>
</ul>
```

The result should be

```
<li><img class="test" src="secret/photo.jpg" title="Tester1"></li>
<li><img class="test" src="secret/photo.jpg" title="Tester2"></li>
<li><img class="test" src="secret/photo2.jpg" title="Tester2"></li>
```

I've used this function but it doesn't work.

```
function unique(array) {
    return $.grep(array, function(el, index) {
        return index == $.inArray(el, array);
    });
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Please post your array that you pass to your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var $lis = $('ul li').filter(function () {
    var $img = $(this).find('img'),
        src = $img.attr('src'),
        title = $img.attr('title');
    return $(this).nextAll('li:has(img[src="' + src + '"][title="' + title + '"])').length == 0
})

$('ul li').not($lis).remove()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9BkMc/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8aV3v/).

Operator `==` returns true only if element is identical, not if they have same content. Then, you have to store into array titles and then check if title is in the array or not.

```
function unique(array) {
    var titles = [];
    return $.grep(array, function (el, index) {
        var $img = $('img', el);
        if ($.inArray($img.prop('title'), titles) >= 0) {
            return false;
        }
        titles.push($img.prop('title'));
        return true;
    });
}
```

I passed a array value into function this way.

```
unique($('li'))
```

If you want pass something like this `unique($('li img'))` you can, but you have to change this line `var $img = $('img', el);` too (`var $img = $(el);` is enough in this case).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that creates a string by concatenating title and URL of the `img` and then checks for unique strings in the list.

(after giving the id `myul` to `ul`)

```
<ul id="myul">
```

Javascript/JQuery:

```
uniqueLi = {};

$("#myul li").each(function () {
    var thisTxt = $('img', this).attr("title");
    var thisImg = $('img', this).attr("src");
    var uString = thisTxt.concat(thisImg);
    if (!(uString in uniqueLi)) {
        uniqueLi[uString] = "";
    } else {
        $(this).remove();
    }
})
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B6A2B/